# This code works in Chrome but not in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, setinterval

I can get this code to work in Chrome, but not in IE(internet explorer). Is it possible to migrate some stuff over to other browsers as browser cross compatibility?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>#move{position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:cyan}</style>
<script>
var ok=document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(ok);
ok.setAttribute("id","move");
function jobson(a){
switch(a){
case 0:
setInterval(function(){    
if(ok.style.backgroundColor="black")ok.style.backgroundColor="cyan"},1);
break;
};
setInterval(function(){
if(ok.style.backgroundColor="cyan")ok.style.backgroundColor="black";ok.style.left
(a)+"px";},1);
//distancia
};
setInterval(function(){
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
jobson(i);
};},1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/233fW/)

Comment: It's Internet Explorer, What do you expect... -_-

Answer (score 0):

Youre overloading the browsers memory and causing it to crash since you are calling your `setTimeout` every 1 millisecond.

Change this (every 1 millisecond):

```
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        jobson(i);
    };
}, 1);
```

To this (every 100 milliseconds):

```
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        jobson(i);
    };
}, 100);
```

**If you want a CSS3 only solution:**

CSS:

```
#move {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:20px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:cyan;
    animation:myanimation 1s;
    -moz-animation:myanimation 1s;
    -webkit-animation:myanimation 1s;
}
@keyframes myanimation {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left:500px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes myanimation {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left:500px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left:500px;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTJ7X/2/)

Comment: I'm trying to use one DIV to move simultaneously across the screen, and by far I know it's possible at least in Google Chrome.

Comment: Would you be open to using a library such as jQuery?

Comment: Yes I'm open to, although if had to pick I choose javascript.

Comment: @user2887761 - Check out my updated answer. Uses CSS only. No Javascript needed.

Comment: I'm sorry must expressed wrong what I'm trying to do here. Not animation at all, but to fill the screen instead of 100 DIVs use only one that can be in simultaneously in different places. With that said, you comprehend that one DIV works for 100. This is what meant, not animation but I need to use setInterval somewhere or otherwise the for loop would be static and go directly to the last position which is happening to internet explorer.